# Plot vector (or arc) onto a rose plot. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, rose-plot

I have two datasets. One detailing a list of `angles` (which I am plotting onto a rose plot):

```
angles
-0.8481065519
0.0367932161
2.6273740453
...
n
```

The other, detailing directional statistics from this group of angles:

```
angle,error
-0.848106563,0.8452778824
```

Where `angle` essentially defines the directional mean, and `error` the circular variance, essentially an error bar either side of the `angle`

I have thus far plotted a rose histogram using the set of angles, as such:

```
h = rose(angles,36)
```

I would like to create a plot of the directional statistic `angle` (it does not need a length/magnitude - just to the edge of the circle plot) with the `error` around it.
As an example:

[image: An example of what I want to do.]

I added the lines by hand in Matlab. If possible it would be good to perhaps have shading within the arc too. Alternatively, (and possibly preferred) would be to have just a sliver above the rose plot bins (so it doesn't cover the data) with a centre line (showing the `angle` and shading surrounding for the `error`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
%// Data
angles = 2*pi*.8*randn(1,1e4);
angle = -0.848106563;
error = 0.8452778824;

%// Plot rose
rose(angles, 36);
axis image %// make axis square
hold on

%// Plot mean
a = axis;
a = a(2); %// size of axis
plot([0 cos(angle)*a], [0 sin(angle)*a], 'r')

%// Plot error as many shaded triangles that compose a circular wedge
t = linspace(-error/2+angle,error/2+angle,100); %// increase "100" if needed
for k = 1:numel(t)-1
    h = patch([0 cos(t(k))*a cos(t(k+1))*a 0], ...
        [0 sin(t(k))*a sin(t(k+1))*a 0], [.5 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
        %// change color [.5 0 0] to something else if desired. Note also alpha
    set(h,'Facealpha',.3) %// make transparent
end     

%// Place rose on top by rearranging order of axis children
ch = get(gca,'children');
set(gca,'children',[ch(2:end); ch(1)]);
```

[image]

For this to work, you need to use a figure renderer capable of transparency. So you may need to adjust the figure's `renderer` property.

Comment: This is great! Many thanks. It all seems to work fine, bar when it is being displayed -- strangely, however, on the figure the shaded error arc is covering the rose plot, and I can only see that. Any ideas?

When I rotate the figure (on a 3D axis) the rose plot beneath seems to clip through, however.

Comment: That has to do with the transparency. So maybe it's a problem with the figure's `renderer` property. Try setting it to something else: `set(gcf,'renderer',...)`. See [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html)